# Low temperature behavior for ferromagnets: theoretical and experimental discrepancies

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, calculus, approximations, ferromagnetism

This is in reference to page 326, 327 of *introduction to solid state physics, 8th edition by Charles Kittel*

> *The mean field theory does not give a good description of the variation of $M$ at low temperature. For $T<<T_{c}$ the argument of $\tanh$ in (9) is large and $\tanh(\xi) = 1 - 2e^{-2\xi}$ + ..*

This appears to be a Taylor expansion for $\tanh$ but the fact that there is an exponential term is foreign to me.

Question:

1. Can anyone shed some insight on how the expression for $\tanh(\xi)$ provided by the author came to be?
2. Am I correct to understand that $M(0)$ is the temperature at $T =0$ for the magnetisation given in **(8)** on page 362?  Even better is someone could show the steps behind which the magnetic deviation $\delta M$ in (10) came about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start from the definition of $\tanh x$ in terms of exponentials
\begin{align}
\tanh x &= \frac{e^x -e^{-x}}{e^x +e^{-x}}\\
&= \frac{1 - e^{-2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}}\\
&=(1 - e^{-2x})\left(1 - e^{-2x} + O(e^{-4x})\right)\\
&=1 - 2e^{-2x} + O(e^{-4x})\;,
\end{align}
where in the second last line we have Taylor expanded in powers of $e^{-2x}$.

Comment: Thank you - I was previously able to get to the second equality but was stumped. This helps.

Answer (score 5):

For the first question you can rewrite $\tanh$ in terms of exponentials, see e.g. [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57746/535160) for details. For the second question, yes, $M(0)$ is the magnetization in the zero temperature limit, where you approximate $\tanh \xi \approx 1$.

Comment: Thank you - this is certainly also verified by the physics. At $T \rightarrow 0$, all magnetic dipoles are perfectly aligned with the direction of the external magnetic field (there is insufficient thermal energy to allow for the higher (spin down) energy states to be populated.

So, $M \approx N\mu$